# Is there a way to show people why their -1 was wrong?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

So my question comes from [How to automatically hide files put in a specific folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/645357/how-to-automatically-hide-files-put-in-a-specific-folder?noredirect=1#645358) Bon Gart was very quick to downvote my answer (be sure to look at it post terdon's edit) Is there anyway, other than just tagging them in a comment explaining why they were wrong because they didn't read the whole post, to get those downvotes rectified?

Comment: Bon Gart provided a reason for the downvote.  Some people would have just downvoted the answer without a reason.  You should work on improving the answer instead of worrying about a little reputation.

Comment: More importantly, Terdon edited the answer, removed what I downvoted about, and **I removed my downvote**.  Interesting how that little detail was left out of this drama.  However, you are insisting that I was wrong in downvoting you, yet I am not the only person who believed you were wrong in that portion of what you said... thus earning the downvote.  You have not restored your answer to include what you originally said because **you agree** that it was incorrect to say that part.  If you stand by what you said, you wouldn't have allowed the edit to stand.

Answer (score 8):

Wrong can be subjective, so not really.

You can edit your post to address/correct the issue if there are comments saying why it might be wrong. Or can leave a comment as a heads up.

These are pretty much your only two options.

Either you can convince them, or you can't.

Comment: So, just tell them they're wrong and hope they have the good wil to fix it.

Comment: That's all you have, which may not be what you want to hear, but that's how the system and people work.

Comment: @PsychoData And I told you where you were wrong, and you didn't think you should fix it.

Answer (score -5):

Man, when gains a privilege to "destroy" the others in some way use it no matter why. The same happen for questions, there are the guidelines if a question follow them there are no need to down vote it, most of the question are downvoted only because are made by newbie.

Down vote should be followed by an obligatory comment!

Comment: I note that when you hover over a downvote arrow, it actually mentions why something was downvoted. There used to be a penalty for downvoting questions but TPTB got rid of it.